# Can't update file name in Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to update a file in Google Drive using Java.

```
File f =
drive.files().update(fileId, null).setAddParents(newParentId).setRemoveParents(oldParentId).set("name", "new name").execute();
```

The parent folder is updated, but the file name is not updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Filename or title belongs to metadata according to [Working with File and Folder Metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata) guide.

> "Metadata is encapsulated in the Metadata class and contains all
>   details about a file or folder including the title, the MIME type, and
>   whether the file is editable, starred or trashed."

To change/update a metadata, you'll be using [MetadataChangeSet](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/MetadataChangeSet).

> "The metadata may be set or changed when creating or updating a file
>   by using a MetadataChangeSet, setting the appropriate values, and then
>   calling the DriveResource.updateMetadata method."

```
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
.setStarred(true)
.setIndexableText("Description about the file")
.setTitle("A new title").build(); //change/update demo
file.updateMetadata(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
.setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
```

Full sample is in [Android drive demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/EditMetadataActivity.java).

Comment: This development is not android one. I am following the https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update
The file name could be updated with the UI. May I ask if "Patch body" is mapping to set()?